# Laravel relationship returns NULL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm try to get relations via laravel Eloquement model. I'm have two models ex Books.php and Magazine.php

in Books.php i have

```
public function magazines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\BOOKS', 'id', 'id');
}
```

Then i'm try to return all magazines, which relate with books

```
$books = Book::find(123);
$magazines = $books->magazines()->get();
return $magazines;
```

but i'm have NULL magazines! When i'm add

```
$magazines = $books->magazines()->toSql();
```

i'm see this select: **select * from "MAGAZINE" where "MAGAZINE"."ID" is null and "MAGAZINE"."ID" is not null** - what is it? Why laravel model put "is null and is not null"?

Notice, if i'm change

```
public function magazines()
{
    return $this->belongsToo('App\BOOKS', 'id', 'id');
}
```

Select would be like this: **select * from "MAGAZINE" where "MAGAZINE"."ID" is null**
Anyone know, what is this?

Comment: show table structure for books table

Comment: I do not think your relationship makes sense. Why a Book hasMany Books? Shouldn't a Book belongsToMany magazines?

Comment: I imagine the class your are referencing in the relationship doesn't exist. Try changing the class you are referring to in the `hasMany` from `App\BOOKS` to `App\Book`.

Comment: friends, it's an example.. the real table locate in the Oracle, with many columns and rows. But i'm think the structure of query is not right.. Why model put 'is null' ?

Comment: The query structure is not right because the relationship is not right. Fixing the relationship will fix the query.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code:

- `HasMany` takes as first parameter the related model class so in your case is pointless to pass `App\Book`. You should pass `App\Magazine` assuming that your magazine model is called `Magazine`
- you are not saying to the `HasMany` relationship what is the name of the foreign key on your `magazines` table.

That should do the job

```
public function magazines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Magazine', 'book_id', 'id');
}
```

IMHO i suggest you to read the Laravel documentation before posting here, there are a lot of examples that will explain to you how to work with relationships and database tables. Take a look to [One to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationships.

**EDIT**

You can omit the `->get()` on the relationship and simply fetch your magazines doing

```
$magazines = $books->magazines;
```

Comment: this model laravel generated automatically for projec

Comment: when i'm change model class, names of tables changed, but "is not null and is null" still in the query

Comment: Automatically generated methods are only stubs, you have always to modify it to reflect the correct DB structure. Have you changed the `hasMany` method adding your foreign key as second parameter and your local key as first parameter?

Comment: Then check that everything is correct in your DB and in your model definition

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

Please change and try:

```
public function magazines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\MAGAZINE');
}
```

Comment: No, i'm have different foreign_key and primary_id

Comment: @KonstantinMokhov Please provide in details